# How to check what values are consumed by a spring boot java application from the Linux command line or in the docker container

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, email

How to check what values are consumed by a  spring boot java application from the Linux command line or in the docker container?

I have a spring boot java application that has the below parameters for email

```
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=admin@qtech.com
spring.mail.password=${GPASSWORD}
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.ssl.trust=smtp.gmail.com
```

I'm passing GPASSWORD as an environment variable to the docker/k8s container.

How can I check what value/values are being consumed by the java application, especially spring.mail.password field.

I tried the below commands

```
printenv 

env
```

But they list all environment variables being passed to all containers like the below environment variable.

```
GPASSWORD=bond007
```

So Is there a way to check what values are being consumed by the spring boot java application inside a pod or container?

Comment: How about logging them on application startup, and then look at the log?

Comment: Have you used `@Value` annotation inside your application or there is another way you access them while running application

Comment: @AshishPatil is there a way with which we can find it from the command line terminal inside a docker container or k8s pod.

Comment: @devops-admin :   As far as I can see, there is no straight-forward way of obtaining application properties in a manner you are looking for.  You can use `CommandLineRunner` / `ApplicationRunner` interfaces of spring but again those will return  you properties while application is starting up. 
Another way of is to create `Actuator` or `rest-endpoint` which will return you application properties & call this rest-endpoint via `curl`  anytime after application is started.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Slf4j annotation and log like below:

```
@Value("${spring.mail.host}")
private String mailHost;

log.info("spring.mail.host: "+mailHost);
```